# For Ubuntu 22.10 installation using Something Else is UEFIi system mandatory

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 20.10

**Ubuntu 22.10 Installation using Something Else.**

Is using the UEFI system mandatory or not?

If not mandatory, how do I disable the UEFI partition?

Comment: My laptop is Legacy only and I use  "Something else" when installing Ubuntu to attached drives, no problem either MBR or GPT.

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory for GPT-formatted disks (sorta. You probably don't want to open that can of worms). If you don't want UEFI, you need an MBR disk, you should ensure that legacy boot/BIOS compatibility is enabled in your motherboard's settings, and you should boot your install media in BIOS compatibility/legacy mode.

Comment: Many very new systems now are UEFI Class 3 or they have no CSM mode. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode  Microsoft has required gpt partitioning with all UEFI installs of Windows since 2012. Ubuntu allows UEFI install to MBR drives but probably should not as it often leads to misconfigured systems.  And you can use gpt with BIOS boot if you have a bios_grub partition. For whatever reason the installer adds an ESP - efi system partition to all installs whether UEFI or BIOS. Perhaps assuming user will later convert to UEFI if in BIOS mode.

Comment: @oldfred Please post your comment as an answer, so I don't have to do something stupid like basically plagiarize it.

Comment: The issue is, that the installation procedure of Ubuntu 22.10 in the "something else" stage asks for the efi partition whereas the machnine is Bios and the disk is Mbr.